# Extent report not generated when script abruptly ends

Tags: selenium, selenium-extent-report

I have POM based selenium framework,i am using extent reports and the reports are generated fine if all of the scripts run. If one of the script fails abruptly due to browser disappear then my script is failing and then report is not generated.
Ex: I have 3 scripts to run as part of my driver script, when 3rd script is running if something goes wrong(like browser disappear) then report is not generated. I want extent report generated whenever it fails/stops. My driver script has extent.flush which is the last execution as part of scripts. How can we generate report on failure. If the failure is due to object not found then i am able to get the report. 
How to generate report whenever i stop the execution?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
thanks
Raju

Comment: The answer depends on your framework.  TestNG/Junit?  Cucumber/JBehave/OtherBDD?  The key is that you need to place the code that flushes the report in an AfterClass, AfterTest, or AfterSOMETHING depending on how you answer my previous question.  Also, you're new.  See my next comment for some friendly advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I will try to ask in better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using TestNG if that is true add the parameter *alwaysRun = true*  in the TestNG methods e.g.

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeMethod()
//your_code
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterMethod() {
 //your_code
}
```